# MySQL update subquery can't specify table target issue

Tags: mysql

I have been going through many queries, but can't seem to find the right combination to get this to work. I get the error "You can't specify target table 't1' for update in FROM clause". I know MySQL doesn't like the subquery in the update statement and have read about wrapping it in other select statements, but can't seem to figure it out. Here is a stripped down query of what I am looking for:

```
UPDATE myTable t1 SET t1.num=concat(t1.num,'B') WHERE t1.num in ('1','2') and t1.expiry=(SELECT max(t2.expiry) from myTable t2 where t2.num=t1.num);
```

Basically trying to get the latest date (expiry) for each number (num) and change the number where applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should works :

```
UPDATE myTable t1, (SELECT num, max(expiry) expiry from myTable t2 group by num) t2
SET t1.num = concat(t1.num,'B')
WHERE t1.num in ('1','2')
and t1.expiry = t2.expiry
and t1.num = t2.num;
```